# Question related to L-arginine biosynthesis

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry

With respect to the [L-arginine Biosynthesis pathway](http://biocyc.org/ECOLI/NEW-IMAGE?type=PATHWAY&object=ARGSYN-PWY), the very first reaction converts [L-glutamate to N-acetyl L-glutamate](http://biocyc.org/ECOLI/NEW-IMAGE?type=REACTION-IN-PATHWAY&object=N-ACETYLTRANSFER-RXN).

In the linked reaction scheme, why are only L-glutamate and N-acetyl glutamate considered, and not acetyl-CoA or the coenzyme? Is this because L-glutamate and N-acetyl L-glutamate are the main compounds to be considered? Why are they the main compounds being considered? Are these two compounds (L-glutamate and N-acetyle L-glutamate) the ligands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The synthesis of N-acetylglutamate is mediated by the enzyme *N-acetylglutamate synthase*. This enzyme has **L-glutamate as its substrate** and uses **acetyl-coenzyme A** as a co-enzyme **acetyl donor**. Acetylcoenzyme A (Acetyl-CoA) is generally abbreviated in structural formulas, because it is a relatively complex molecule. The only thing of relevance is the acetyl group which is transferred from a thiol group to L-glutamate.

Note that *ligands* is a term reserved for molecules binding to receptors; *substrates* is the proper term for intermediates in enzymatic reactions.

[image: N-acetylglutamate]
<sup>N-acetylglutamate synthesis. Source: [The Medical Biochemistry page](http://themedicalbiochemistrypage.org/nitrogen-metabolism.php)</sup>